# If $f : \mathbb{R^n_+} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x) = x\stackrel{\cdot}{g}(x)$, find properties associated with it.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

If $f : \mathbb{R^n_+} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x) = x\stackrel{\cdot}{g}(x)$ such that $x\stackrel{\cdot}{g}(x) \leq x \stackrel{\cdot}{g}$ for every $g \in \mathbb{S \subset R^n}$ verify if it is linear/convex/concave/quasi-convex and find the degree of homogeneity, if at all, it is homogenous.

Solution : Given a non-zero $x$, from the given inequality, we have $f(x) \leq f(y) \ \forall \ y \in \mathbb{R^n_+}$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $f$ turns out to be a constant function. Now $f(0) = 0$ tells us that $f$ is identically zero.

I think I have solved it incorrect, I would like to know where I went wrong and what I should have done instead.

Comment: The subscript + on the $R^n$ means the last coordinate is $\geq 0$, right?  What does the dot above the g indicate?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I thought every coordinate has to be $\geq 0$. More like $\mathbb{(R^+)^n}$ but I am not sure. 

Again, I am not very sure of what the dot indicates. I have seen dots being used as the derivates (wrt time) when being used for Differential Equations. So I assume $\stackrel{\cdot}{g} := \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} g$

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?  The text should have definitions of its symbols.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor It's from a test and I copied everything ditto.

Comment: Then the test is from a class and the class has a textbook or lecture notes at least and the textbook or notes has the definitions of the symbols.  Look wherever you got this test from.